# Why does Wubi installation fail with "Error: 'None Type' object has no attribute 'get_info'"?

Tags: installation, windows, wubi

I'm trying to install Wubi from Windows, and it fails half-way with this error:

```
"None Type" object has no attribute 'get_info'
c:\user\hp\Appdata\local\temp\wubi-12.04rev266
```

How can I complete Wubi installation?

Answer (score 3):

Don't mount the image file, just put wubi.exe and the iso in same folder and then try, Don't mount it through any software

Answer (score 2):

#### Known bug, please re-download the ISO and verify MD5 hash

It appears this is a catch-all error usually thrown (shown) by [Wubi not recognizing or reading some piece of data in the ISO](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1641044) used for installation, which in turn is caused [by an error while downloading the ISO](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+bug/989991).

Please try *separately* downloading the 12.04 i386 desktop ISO, and verify that the MD5 hash matches. Then launch Wubi and point it to the downloaded ISO.

Comment: Can I have a link to the bug report?

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS, it's the second link, but for you, a special mention :p  : https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+bug/989991

Comment: Ah. They were buried and I had no idea the link was to a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem a few times on my Dell XPS 13. I'm trying some command to start Wubi but am not sure if it works or not, it seems to be working.

Use the command prompt to run it with:

```
D:/wubi.exe --force-wubi
```

Replace `D` with your drive letter. (Mine was actually in `E`.) Good luck.