# Wubi gives error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_info'

Tags: installation, wubi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does Wubi installation fail with “Error: 'None Type' object has no attribute 'get_info'”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/154102/why-does-wubi-installation-fail-with-error-none-type-object-has-no-attribute)

while installing through wubi , an error occurs

'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_info' 
For more information see the log file . ...